# WPF Turn ComboBox TextBox background red when it's invalid

Tags: wpf

I'm developing a custom control that I call EnhancedComboBox that I hope will provide some enhanced features to the standard ComboBox.  Among them will be the ability to turn the TextBox portion background yellow if the focus is on the control, but the text in the TextBox does not match the selected item, or red when the same condition is met when the focus is off of the control.

I have spent the last day and a half searching all over the web for help on this, but have not found this exact set of conditions, nor have I uncovered sufficient explanations as to *why* the author is writing the xaml the way he does. The control builds and operates just fine, with the exception that the background color doesn't ever change. What am I missing?

```
<ComboBox x:Class="CHIMS_Data_Entry_Controls.EnhancedComboBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CHIMS_Data_Entry_Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True">

    <ComboBox.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="CautionColor">#FFFFFF00</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ErrorColor">#FFFF0000</Color>
    <Style x:Key="EnhancedComboBox" TargetType="local:EnhancedComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:EnhancedComboBox">
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource CautionColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>

</ComboBox>
```

### Update

In response to Andy's comments, I have already tried writing code-behind to handle this and have had more success with that.  I've traced the code and see that it finds the ComboBox's TextBox and even sets its Background to the correct color.  But, the color is not actually displayed.

I understand that these controls use their default colors and behavior, even if one writes programmatically to them, so how do I get the control to actually display the color I want?

Here is my code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;    
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CHIMS_Data_Entry_Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EnhancedComboBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EnhancedComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        private Brush _defaultBackground;

        public EnhancedComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _defaultBackground = Background;
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsTextInList)
            {
                    _myTextBox.Background = _defaultBackground;
            }
            else
            {
                    _myTextBox.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsTextInList)
            {
                    _myTextBox.Background = _defaultBackground;
            }
            else
            {
                    _myTextBox.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }

        public bool IsTextInList
        {
            get
            {
                bool _isFound = false;
                string _wasFound = " not";

                foreach (string Element in Items)
                {
                    if (Text == Element)
                    {
                        _isFound = true;
                        _wasFound = "";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return _isFound;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I know that this will only fire when entering or leaving the control and not as the text in the TextBox changes, but until I find a way to capture the OnTextChanged of the TextBox, this will have to do, at least to prove that I can effect the desired change in the background.

At this point, I think the key thing for me as far as the code-back goes is to figure out how to get the TextBox to actually display the Background I've set it to, and that's what I'm asking for your help with.

Comment: That template cannot actually be the template of your control. It has nothing in it. No popup, no textbox, no button. It's nothing like a combobox template.

Comment: I'm new to this, so perhaps I misunderstand what's needed in a template.  I thought that since this is derived from a WPF ComboBox, all those things already existed as elements of the existing ComboBox and the only thing that was needed in the template was to reference that ComboBox.

Comment: A wpf control is totally lookless. The template defines what it is. Replace the template with something has no controls in it and you have nothing on screen. This is not a beginners sort of task you've given yourself. Btw a control will often have behaviour via some code. That often works with parts given specific names.

Comment: Thanks.  I've looked at several books and a lot of websites, and they show what to do, but are short on telling me why.  Can you recommend some place to go or book to read that can do that?

Comment: Not really. I mentor and teach, but it's rather secondary to architecting, designing, leading and developing. I have a bunch of articles and samples you might find interesting. One of these is a get-you-started which is intended to help someone understand what's involved in a combox like control. My TechNet user page has links https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30959.user-page-andy-oneill.aspx I think rather than templating a combobox I'd probably do a usercontrol. Customising controls is tricky and usercontrols should be your first choice. Especially whilst learning,